# Как навсегда указать учётные данные для прокси в Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Каждый раз, когда захожу в VS, она просит логин и пароль от прокси. Если ввожу, хватает только на одну сессию, в следующий раз захожу и снова.

Вопрос: можно ли где-то в настройках прописать логин и пароль для прокси, чтобы VS сама подключалась к нему, не спрашивая у меня каждый раз? Либо каким-то другим способом настроить, чтобы VS запомнила, наконец, мои учётные данные от прокси, как это делает, например, браузер.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [WinDivert](https://www.reqrypt.org/windivert.html) для проксифирования трафика отдельных приложений. То есть, создать правило на приложение Visual Studio перенаправлять трафик через заранее добавленные списки прокси. Есть возможность использовать последовательные цепочки из прокси-серверов. Программа, конечно не очень удобная. Чтобы ей пользоваться, надо быть программистом. Многие настройки WinDivert устанавливаются через сам исходный код WinDivert, либо свой код подключая WinDivert как модуль. Но у WinDivert есть отличный доработанный платный аналог с GUI - [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/). Я конечно не буду призывать к пиратству, но факт есть факт, прога лежит на популярных торрент-трекерах.

Просто установите в параметрах соединения VS прямое подключение без прокси-сервера. Proxifier (или WinDivert) сами подхватят все соединения VS. Запустите Proxifier, добавьте все возможные прокси (или прокси-листы). Далее запустите VS, и как только VS начнет ломиться в интернет, вы увидите  процесс в списке Proxifier, далее кликаете на процесс правой кнопкой и из меню выбираете нужный для соединения маршрут. Собственно, правило создано. Настройки Proxifier по-умолчанию установлены на сохранение правил после завершения работы программы. Если поставить легковесную утилиту загружаться с запуском компьютера, про ввод логина-пароля для прокси (да и вообще даже само наличие этой прокси) можно забыть. Все будет работать автоматически.

Сами Proxifier и WinDivert работают незаметно, как вирусы - то есть они не жрут CPU больше необходимого и не жрут ОЗУ больше 2-3Mb. В целом, исходный код WinDivert используют во многих троянах, ботнетах и прочих программах, где необходим перехват/подмена/фильтрация трафика.

[image: proxifier]

Comment: Спасибо, ответ однозначно полезный, но всё же мне хотелось бы узнать, как сделать это средствами самой VS и Windows, без помощи стороннего ПО. Раньше ведь это как-то работало.

Comment: Согласен. Hо трафик контролировать тоже полезно. У вас же на Windows есть же какой-нибудь другой фаэрвол, в котором вы создаете правила для каждого приложения?

Answer (score 1):

Укажите в настройках сервера прокси логин и пароль, например так:

```
http://user:password@proxyIP:proxyPort/
```

Настройки примерно в файле `devenv.exe.config`

Могут возникнуть проблемы если в вашем пароле или логине содержаться спецсимволы, но это уже другая история

Comment: Пробовал. Это не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Пол года спустя разобрался. Помог ответ [отсюда](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/e6d8a368-0537-41a6-9568-a71818724ae7/windows-7-10871077108810771089109010721083?forum=windows7ru) вот [этого](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/itd27m01/?ws=usercard-mini) прекрасного человека.

Решение: нужно зайти Панель управления -> Диспетчер учётных данных -> Учётные данные Windows. Найти там строку с адресом прокси, нажать галочку вниз, "Удалить". Далее снова зайти в VS, ввести логин и пароль, поставить галку "запомнить". И теперь он действительно запомнит! Т.е. при последующих входах в VS повторный ввод не потребуется.